# how to revert back the width and height of the images once modified

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am showing some content along with images on the webpage. Each image comes with certain width or may not have width specified. When user click on a button, the content on the webpage is exported to the PDF file so to fit images in the PDF page i'm modifying the width and height of the images, but it is modifyng the width an height of the images on the webpage too. How can i stop to change the width and height of the images on the webpage.

Please find the demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/STVjUB1YMwbOrtYLxR8V?p=preview

In the above demo plunker, when clicked on the export button, the image width and height are modified so that when the data is exported to the PDF the images fit correctly in the PDF page, and the modified images width/height changes can be seen on the webpage too. How can i restrict so that the modified images width and height are only  applied to the PDF file but not on the webpage.

html code:

```
<button ng-click="export()">export</button>
<div class="myDivClass"..>
 <img src="data:image/jpeg..">
 <img src="..." style="width:400px">
 ..
 //content
</div>
```

js code:

```
$scope.export = function() {
         var imagesToResize = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
         for(i=0;i<imagesToResize.length;i++){
            imagesToResize[i].style.width = "100px";
            imagesToResize[i].style.height = "100px";
        }
```

Any inputs are helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--- Edit---------------------------------------------------------

So after digging a bit into the problem I realized that the problem was  that a simple document.getElementByTagName('img') and modifying the entire img's is not appropriate ,for instance if you just want some printable img to have a custom height and width , you cannot just suddenly shrink and re-grow all the images , so it's a better approach to take your printable content to a hidden div and then in the hidden div do all the maninpulation and then use that hidden div for printable content. I even made a git repo which you can see and see that if your problem is solved or not.
git link : https://github.com/sagarb3/jspdf-demo

In the git link i kept the downloaded images as the base64 of images was making the whole thing a bit ugly . I even modified some functions

I didn't have a very good understanding of jspdf but I came up finally with a solution

this is how my index.html looks now

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.2.0" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>
-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.33/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>
 -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="listController">
        <button ng-click="export()">export</button>
        <div id="content-div">
            <div id="{{value.pageIndex}}" ng-repeat="(key, value) in employees" class="myDivClass" style="background-color:white">
                <h1><span style="background-color: yellow">{{value.pageIndex}}</span>




    <div>  
    <h1>
    <p style="color:red"> {{value.pageHeader}}</p></h1>
            </div>
            <p> A variation of the ordinary lorem ipsum text has been used in typesetting since the 1960s or earlier, when it was popularized by advertisements for Letraset transfer sheets. It was introduced to the Information Age in the mid-1980s by Aldus Corporation, which employed it in graphics and word-processing templates for its desktop publishing program PageMaker.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce egestas elementum justo sed placerat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce egestas elementum justo sed placerat.</p>
            <img alt="" src="download2.jpg" class="image-responsive" style="width: 800px;" />
            <img src="download.png" style="width: 400px;" />
            <h1>One more image</h1>
            <h1>This is last line displayed in the page</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pdf-content" style="display:none">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is the js file with the solution:

```
 var app = angular.module("app", []);

 app.controller("listController", ["$scope", '$timeout',
     function($scope, $timeout) {

         $scope.employees = [{ pageIndex: "div1", pageHeader: "This should be shown in page1" },
             { pageIndex: "div2", pageHeader: "This should be shown in page2" }
         ];


         $scope.export = function() {
             var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'A4');
             var pdfName = 'test.pdf';
             var vDom = $('#pdf-content').html($('#content-div').html());
             //console.log(vDom);
             var elementHandler = {
                 '#skipExport': function(element, renderer) {
                     return true;
                 }
             }
             var options = {
                 'elementHandlers': elementHandler
             };
             function formatHtml() {                
                 var imagesToResize = document.getElementById('pdf-content').getElementsByTagName("img");
                 for (i = 0; i < imagesToResize.length; i++) {
                     (function(i) {
                         imagesToResize[i].style.width = "100px";
                         imagesToResize[i].style.height = "100px";
                     })(i);
                 }
                 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                     resolve('success');
                     reject('err');
                 })
             }
             formatHtml().then(function(res) {
                 $("#pdf-content").find(".myDivClass").each(function(index) {
                     pdf.fromHTML($(this).html(),15, 20, options, function(){
                        pdf.addPage();
                     })
                 })
                 $timeout(function() {
                     pdf.save(pdfName);
                 }, 3000);

             })

         }
     }




 ])
```

;